# UIAlertController and memory usage

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, swift3, uialertcontroller

I have a very simple project: there's only one `ViewController` and a `UIButton`. The `IBAction` for the button is:

```
var alertViewControllerTextField: UITextField?

var promptController = UIAlertController(title: "Type Something", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                print("\(alertViewControllerTextField?.text)")
            })

let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in
                //promptController = nil
            }
            promptController.addAction(ok)
            promptController.addAction(cancel)
            promptController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
                alertViewControllerTextField = textField
            }
            self.present(promptController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When the app finishes launching, memory usage is 14,4 Mb.

When I click the button it reaches 18,4 Mb (if I click again and again the button, it finally reaches 20 Mb).

Anyway, I thought when I clicked the UIAlertController's **cancel** or **ok** button, memory would have returned to 14,4, even slowly, but this is not the case.

I thought to make the `UIAlertController` an `optional` to have the chance to assign it a `nil` on close, but the `UIAlertController` can't be `nil` because you can't declare it as an optional. I thought to make it a member and declare it with the `weak` keyword (no luck).

So, is there any way to reduce the memory usage when I click one of the buttons of a UIAlertController?

Comment: Is this in the simulator or on device?

Comment: It's in the simulator, haven't tried on device

Comment: Try it on device. Memory usage in the simulator doesn't provide an accurate representation.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I try

Comment: @jjatie: it's the same. The only difference is that the project initially uses 4 Mb, not 14

Comment: @might be a bug in the memory inspector of Xcode. Try using instruments to verify

Comment: @Anish웃 Instruments shows the same behavior. It looks like a UIAlertController is just like diamonds: it's forever   :-)

Comment: What the hell is going on today..Unexpected results everywhere

Answer (score 0):

**PLease Put DispatchQueue this code than try i solved this issue by this**

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async
{
        self.present(promptController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: No, it's the same

Answer (score 0):

I have seen elsewhere that you need to declare the `alertViewControllerTextField` weak so that the actions don't retain it. (Not sure I fully understand this yet.)

So try:

```
var alertViewControllerTextField: UITextField?

var promptController = UIAlertController(title: "Type Something", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alertViewControllerTextField](action) -> Void in
                print("\(alertViewControllerTextField?.text)")
            })

let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { [weak promptController] (action) -> Void in
                //promptController = nil
            }

promptController.addAction(ok)
promptController.addAction(cancel)
promptController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
                alertViewControllerTextField = textField
            }
self.present(promptController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```